# Resource NotFound Exception of TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Unable to retrieve data in listview form SQLite .When I run the app my app is crashes.
I don't know where is the actual problems. Can someone help me out how to retrieve all the data in listview.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my Adapter code.

```
public class EmployeeList_Adapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Employee> Employee_List;


    public EmployeeList_Adapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Employee> employee_List) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        Employee_List = employee_List;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Employee_List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Employee_List.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee EmployeeListItems = Employee_List.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.staff_employee_list_item, null);
        }
        TextView tvEmpId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_emp_Id);
        tvEmpId.setText(EmployeeListItems.getEmployeeId());


        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_Emp_ame);
        tvName.setText(EmployeeListItems.getName());

        TextView tvDepartment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_Emp_Department);
        tvDepartment.setText(EmployeeListItems.getDepartment());

        TextView tvDesignation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewStaff_Emp_Designation);
        tvDesignation.setText(EmployeeListItems.getDesignation());

        return convertView;
    }


}


Here is my Activity code

public class Employee_List extends Activity
{
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Context mContext;
    Employee emp;

    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    ListView listEmployee;
     SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

     public static final String EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_TABLE = "employee_details";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staff_employee_list);
        listEmployee = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        showList();

    }


    private void showList()
    {     ArrayList<Employee> EmployeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();  
    EmployeeList.clear();   
    String query = "SELECT * FROM employee_details";  
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

    //Cursor c1 =db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) 
    {   
        if (c1.moveToFirst())
    {   
            do
            {    
                Employee EmployeeListItems = new Employee();  
                EmployeeListItems.setEmployeeId(c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                EmployeeListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("staff_emp_name")));
                EmployeeListItems.setDepartment(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("department")));
                EmployeeListItems.setDesignation(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("designation")));


                EmployeeList.add(EmployeeListItems);     

            } while (c1.moveToNext());   
            } 
        } 

        EmployeeList_Adapter contactListAdapter = new EmployeeList_Adapter(Employee_List.this, EmployeeList); 
        listEmployee.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);  
        }   
}



Here is pojo class 

public class Employee

{
    int employeeId;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    private String designation;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(int employeeId, String name, String department,
            String designation) {
        super();
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public Employee(String str_employeeName, String str_Department,
            String str_Designation) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name = str_employeeName;
        this.department = str_Department;
        this.designation = str_Designation;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }


}


Log cat error

06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2857)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at com.sqlitedemo.EmployeeList_Adapter.getView(EmployeeList_Adapter.java:55)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
06-29 15:22:00.434: E/AndroidRuntime(639):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
tvEmpId.setText(EmployeeListItems.getEmployeeId());
```

by

```
tvEmpId.setText(EmployeeListItems.getEmployeeId()+"");
```

Comment: Boulifan : My code is working thanks of millions.Thank you so much.